# Aligning responsive images in Twitter Bootstrap

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to align images that occupy two columns in one row on my website. Unfortunatlely, I am unable to acheive the desired result. Below I'm pasting a bootply that explains the problem better than I could with words:

**http://www.bootply.com/VLI1jrLYp9**

I would like the images to be aligned at the bottom at all times, but at the moment the bigger image is always shorter than the group of images on the right. At their natural size, the images are the same height.

Please not that I have removed the outermost gutters from the row. However, even with the gutter in place, the images are still not aligned at the bottom.

I must be missing something realy simple, but please point it out to me.

Thank you!

Answer (score 4):

Unless the padding is the same on all sides of the column, the images will appear at different visual sizes. There's a good bit of adjustment to make, here's an example.

### DEMO: http://jsbin.com/zayiye/1/

*http://jsbin.com/zayiye/1/edit?html,css,output*

[image]

**CSS:**

```
/* demo only */
body {
    /*newer ie covers up content unless this is included*/
    -ms-overflow-style: scrollbar;
}
.full-width {
    padding: 0;
}
/* Flush Grid */
.row.flush-grid {
    overflow: hidden;
    margin-right: 0;
    margin-left: 0;
}
.row.flush-grid [class*="col-"].row {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}
.row.flush-grid [class*="col-"] {
    padding: 0;
    margin-bottom:-1px;
}
.row.flush-grid img {
    width: 100.5%;
    height: auto;
}
@media (min-width:768px) { 
    [class*="col-"].first {
        margin-bottom: 0
    }
    [class*="col-"].last {
        margin-top: 0
    }
    .row.tight-grid [class*="col-"] {
        padding: 0px
    }
    .row.tight-grid [class*="col-"].row {
        padding: 0;
        margin: 0;
    }
}
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="container-fluid full-width">
   <div class="row flush-grid">
      <div class="col-sm-6">
         <img src="http://lorempixel.com/600/400/fashion" alt="">
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-6 row">
         <div class="col-xs-6"><img src="http://lorempixel.com/300/200/nature" alt="" ></div>
         <div class="col-xs-6"><img src="http://lorempixel.com/300/200/food" alt="" ></div>
         <div class="col-xs-6"><img src="http://lorempixel.com/300/200/cats" alt="" ></div>
         <div class="col-xs-6"><img src="http://lorempixel.com/300/200/business" alt="" ></div>
      </div>
   </div>
   <!--/.row.flush-grid -->
   <div class="row flush-grid">
      <div class="col-sm-6 row">
         <div class="col-xs-6"><img src="http://lorempixel.com/300/200/animals" alt="" ></div>
         <div class="col-xs-6"><img src="http://lorempixel.com/300/200/city" alt="" ></div>
         <div class="col-xs-6"><img src="http://lorempixel.com/300/200/people" alt="" ></div>
         <div class="col-xs-6"><img src="http://lorempixel.com/300/200/sports" alt="" ></div>
      </div>
      <!--/.row.flush-grid -->
      <div class="col-sm-6">
         <img src="http://lorempixel.com/600/400/transport" alt="">
      </div>
   </div>
   <!--/.row.flush-grid -->
</div>
<!--/.container-fluid full-width-->
```

Comment: Christina, once again thank you for your reply. This is really helpful. Can I safely keep the padding between the the two columns that hold the images if I use the method that you suggested?

Comment: use negative margins on the row and overflow hidden. As long as the padding is all the same on both sides, it's fine.

Comment: In my example, outermost paddings are removed from both - `col-md-9` and `col-md-3` columns. Images are 100% width of their containing element so they stretch equally far to the edge of the viewport. Unfortunately, they are still misaligned at the bottom. I want them to streth to the edges and I also want to keep this separation between columns. I am still not quite sure how I should modify my example to maintain the separation betweem columns (`col-md-9` and `col-md3`) and have the images aligned properly at the bottom at the same time.

Comment: Well the aspect ratio would need to be figured out and it will still be troublesome but you have to make the padding consistent: http://www.bootply.com/lFQD8dPJAG then remove it only on the .container-fluid. Usually this stuff is done with background images and something to keep the column open (but you still have to find the aspect ratio). There's also some weird tricks that I do. Let me see if I can put something together.

Comment: This is using background images with padding to keep the box open you need to make the smaller viewport css and html this is just for 992px and up it requires jQuery to equalize the heights. http://jsbin.com/yuyoge/1/ and http://jsbin.com/yuyoge/1/edit?html,css,js -- there's no way I can figure out the math on fluid width and height images

Comment: Christina, I think this is exactly what I was looking for. Thank you for bringing up the responsive equal hights plugin. I would tick your last suggestion as the answer if it was not in the comments :) Thank you again!